# Como añadir mi campo clienteid para que se relacione con dni y se envie por un formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Lo único que querría sería crear un select en el campo de formulario del DNI, para cunado tú escojas el DNI, al enviar el formulario en la parte de la vista coja los datos de la tabla clientes. Lo que consigo es no tener que ir poniendo tantos datos en ese formulario pues ya los tengo en mi tabla cliente, solo tendría que pedir el dni para hacer referencia

Mi vista que es lo que se visualizará en la página para ver los datos que tengo:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 AND $_SESSION['rol'] != 2){
header("location: ./");
}
    include("../conexion.php");
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php include("includes/scripts.php"); ?>
    <title>Lista de facturas</title>

</head>
<body>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

    <section id="container">
        <h1>Lista de facturas</h1>
        <hr>
        <?php if($_SESSION['rol'] == 1 OR $_SESSION['rol'] == 2){  ?>

        <a href="nuevafactura.php" class="btn-new">Crear factura</a>
    <?php } ?>
        <form action="buscar_factura.php" method="GET" class="buscar_usuario">
            <input type="text" name="buscador" id="buscador" placeholder="Buscar" class="buscador">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn_buscar">
        </form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Localidad</th>
                <th>Provincia</th>
                <th>País</th>
                <th>Numero factura</th>
                <th>Componente</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
                <th>Pagada</th>
                <!--<th>Componentes</th>-->
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            //PAGINADOR
                $registros = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALFACTURAS FROM facturacliente WHERE estatus = 1");
                $resultadoregistro = mysqli_fetch_array($registros);
                $totalcomponente = $resultadoregistro['TOTALFACTURAS'];
                $numpagina = 10;
                if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
                    # code...
                    $pagina = 1;
                }else{
                    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
                }

                $paginas = ($pagina-1) * $numpagina;//Como sabemos en un array empezamos por la posición 0 y no por la uno, como $pagina vale 1 le restamos 1 para que nos dé 0 y al multiplicalor por 5 dará 0, se hace para que comience desde la posición 1 que en un array es la 0, cuando el valor de $pagina cambie, por darle al botón de paginación 2 se le restará uno y se multiplicará por 5 (2-1) * 5 = 5 y nos enseñaría los siguiente 5 registros. Y así con los demás paginadores.
                $numtotalpagina = ceil($totalcomponente / $numpagina);//Nos servirá para mostrar la cantidad de números en la parte de abajo del paginador, ya que el total de usuarios son 15 por ejemplo y el $numpaginas son 5 es decir la cantidad de usuarios que quiero mostrar por página se dividirá será el número que total de paginadores que deben de salir, es decir, si tengo 15 usuario y quiero mostrar 5 por página 15/5 = 3 botones paginadores. La función ceil redondea por si tenemos 16 usuarios queremos mostrar 5 por lo que redondea para saber cuantas páginas debemos de tener.

                $listacom = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT c.numfactura, c.codigo_componente, o.descripcion, u.dni, u.nombre, u.telefono, u.direccion, u.localidad, u.provincia, u.pais, f.nfacturac, f.cantidad, f.precio, f.totalfactura, f.pagada FROM facturacomponente c INNER JOIN facturacliente f ON c.numfactura = f.nfacturac INNER JOIN componentes o ON c.codigo_componente = o.codcomponente INNER JOIN cliente u ON c.clienteid = u.idcliente WHERE f.estatus = 1 ORDER BY numfactura ASC LIMIT $paginas,$numpagina");
                mysqli_close($conection);
                $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($listacom);
                if($resultado > 0){
                    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($listacom)) {
             ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data["dni"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["nombre"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["telefono"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["direccion"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["localidad"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["provincia"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["pais"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["numfactura"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["descripcion"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["cantidad"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["precio"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["totalfactura"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["pagada"]; ?></td>
                <!--<td><?php//echo $data["nombrecomponente"]; ?></td>-->
                <td>
                    <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] == 1) {
                        # code...
                     ?>
                    <a href="editar_factura.php?id=<?php echo $data["nfacturac"]; ?>" class="link_edit">Editar</a>
                    |
                    <a href="eliminar_factura.php?id=<?php echo $data["nfacturac"]; ?>" class="link_delete">Eliminar</a>
                    <?php

                } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php
                    }

             ?>
        </table>
        <div class="paginador">
            <ul>
                <?php
                    if ($pagina != 1) {
                        # code...

                 ?>

                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1; ?>">|<</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina-1; ?>"><<</a></li>
                <?php
                    }
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $numtotalpagina ; $i++) {
                        # code...
                        if ($i == $pagina) {
                            # code...
                            echo '<li class="seleccionador">'.$i.'</li>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                        if ($pagina != $numtotalpagina) {
                            # code...

                     ?>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1; ?>">>></a></li>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $numtotalpagina; ?>">>|</a>
                        <?php } ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi formulario donde tengo que agregar el campo clienteid para relacionarlo con DNI pero no consigo hacerlo:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 AND $_SESSION['rol'] != 2){
    header("location: ./");
}
include "../conexion.php";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $campos = [
        'dni',
        'nombre',
        'telefono',
        'direccion',
        'localidad',
        'provincia',
        'pais',
        // 'nfacturac',
        // 'nomcomponente'
        'cantidad',
        'precio',
        // 'iva',
        'totalfactura',
    ];
    $alert = '';
    foreach ($campos as $campo) {
        if (empty($_POST[$campo])) {
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">LOS CAMPOS SON OBLIGATORIOS, POR FAVOR RELLÉNELOS</p>';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($alert)) {
        echo $alert;
    } else {
        // campos comunes
        foreach ($campos as $campo) {
            ${$campo} = $_POST[$campo];
        }
        // otros campos
        $pagada             = $_POST['pagada'];
        $nombrecomponente   = $_POST['nombrecomponente'];
        $dni                = $_POST['dni'];
        $usuario            = $_SESSION['idusuario'];

        $insertardatos = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturacliente(dni, nombre, telefono, direccion, localidad, provincia, pais, cantidad, precio, totalfactura, pagada, usuario) VALUES('$dni', '$nombre', '$telefono','$direccion','$localidad','$provincia','$pais','$cantidad','$precio','$totalfactura','$pagada', '$usuario')");

        if ($insertardatos) {
            // insertamos los componentes
            $num_Factura = mysqli_insert_id($conection);


            foreach($nombrecomponente as $codigo_componente) {
                $insertarcomponentes = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturaComponente(numfactura, codigo_componente) VALUES('$num_Factura', '$codigo_componente')");
            }
            $alert = '<p class="msg_save">LOS DATOS SE REGISTRARON</p>';
            echo $alert;
        }else{
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">ERROR AL CREAR EL COMPONENTE</p>';
            echo $alert;
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Nueva Factura</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <section id="container">
        <div class="title_page">
            <h1>Nueva Factura</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_cliente">
            <div class="action_cliente">
                <h4>Datos del Cliente</h4>
                <a href="registro_cliente.php" class="btn-new btn_new_cliente">Nuevo Cliente</a>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST" name="form_new_cliente_venta" id="form_new_cliente_venta" class="datos">
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>DNI</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni">

                </div>-->
                 <div class="wd30">
                    <label>DNI</label>
                    <?php
                    include("../conexion.php");
                    $dni = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT dni FROM cliente");
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($dni);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve

                ?>
                <select name="dni" id="dni"  >
                    <?php
                        if($resultadorol > 0 ) {
                            while ($dni = mysqli_fetch_array($dni)) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $dni["idcliente"]; ?>"><?php echo $dni["dni"] ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
                    <!--Está desactivado-->
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="dir_cliente" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Localidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>País</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>Numero de Factura</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num_cliente" id="num_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <!--
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Componente</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomcomponente" id="nomcomponente" required>
                </div>
                -->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Nombre Componente</label>
                    <?php
                    include("../conexion.php");
                    $descripcion = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM componentes");
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($descripcion);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve

                ?>
                <select name="nombrecomponente[]" id="nombrecomponente" multiple >
                    <?php
                        if($resultadorol > 0 ) {
                            while ($nombrecomponente = mysqli_fetch_array($descripcion)) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $nombrecomponente["codcomponente"]; ?>"><?php echo $nombrecomponente["descripcion"] ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio</label>
                    <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>IVA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="iva_cliente" id="iva_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio Total</label>
                    <input type="text" name="totalfactura" id="totalfactura" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>PAGADA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pagada" id="pagada" required>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn_save">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_venta">
            <h4>Datos Factura</h4>
            <div class="datos">
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Vendedor</label>
                    <p>Manuel Márquez Barragán</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Acciones</label>
                    <div id="acciones_venta">
                        <a href="lista_factura.php" class="btn_ok textcenter" id="btn_anular_venta">Anular</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi relación entre tablas:
[image: Esta sería mi relación de todas mis tablas]

Comment: Podrías utilizar `AJAX` o `Fetch` para que al elegir el DNI en el `<select>` te automplete el resto de los campos del formulario relativos al cliente.

Comment: Manuel, varias cosas... Entre otras, 1) cierras la conexión antes de dejar de trabajar con ella. 2) Después, en tu línea `while ($dni = mysqli_fetch_array($dni))` estás asignando el mismo nombre de variable a la supuesta fila que al propio resultado que habías obtenido en `$dni = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT dni FROM cliente")`.

Comment: @Liyo , si consigo implementar el dni quitaría los demás campos y solo quedaría ese, donde quiero mostrarlo en la plantilla de la vista

Comment: @VFG entonces que debería de poner ? clienteid?

Comment: En todo caso, sería `while ($fila_dni = mysqli_fetch_array($dni)) {` y después algo como `<option value="<?php echo $fila_dni["idcliente"]; ?>"><?php echo $fila_dni["dni"] ?></option>`. De todos modos, como dice @Liyo, lo más conveniente sería un autocomplete alimentado desde el servidor, porque... ¿te imaginas buscar en un select con 2000 filas?

Comment: Pero me han pedido que utilice solo PHP, les propuse la opción de Ajax pero no podía utilizarlo y esto se complica más

Comment: Okey @VFG ahora ya se han solucionado algunos de mis problemas pero en el select del DNI me sale este error:
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key " idcliente" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php on line 103
">20540711D.
Mi línea 103 es:
<option value="<?php echo $fila_dni["idcliente"]; ?>"><?php echo $fila_dni["dni"] ?></option>

Comment: Tu consulta es `"SELECT dni FROM cliente"` y debería ser `"SELECT idcliente,dni FROM cliente"`

Comment: Perfecto ahora toda la visualización está perfecta millones de gracias, pero no se inserta en la base de datos

Comment: Le he añadido a mi consulta el campo clienteid
$insertarcomponentes = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturaComponente(numfactura, codigo_componente, clienteid) VALUES('$num_Factura', '$codigo_componente', '$clienteid')");

Comment: Pero me sale este fallo cuando intento enviarlo
Advertencia : variable no definida $clienteid en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php en la línea 53
La línea 53 es la consulta anterior

Comment: Error fatal : mysqli_sql_exception no detectada: no se puede agregar o actualizar una fila secundaria: falla una restricción de clave externa (`tfg`.`facturacomponente `, RESTRICCIÓN `facturacomponente_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`clienteid`) REFERENCIAS `cliente` (`idcliente`)) en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\ htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php(53): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO fac...') #1 {main} lanzado en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php en la línea 53

Comment: El tema del campo dni nombre direccion localidad provincia y pais de la tabla facturacliente serían borrados

Comment: No voy a seguir porque se hace demasiado largo para tantos problemas (fuera de la pregunta). Pero facturacliente sí debería llevar `localidad`, `provincia`, `pais`.... porque son los que tenía el cliente en el momento de hacerse. Igual que el DNI/NIE/Documento. Si un cliente se cambia de domicilio o de documento (por ejemplo pasa de NIE A DNI por nacionalizarse...) esos datos son inmutables en la factura. Del mismo modo, la factura debería llevar datos del emisor (no sólo del cliente). O en la tabla, o una referencia (id) a una tabla de emisores de facturas.

Comment: Tienes razón no había caido. Muchas graciaas

Comment: @VFG he de darte las gracias, gracias por "abrirme los ojos", ahora realmente sé el porqué de los campos de la factura. Gracias por tu ayuda.